# How to get the forward_host details using apache or php?

Tags: php, apache

how to get the  X-Forwarded-For from PHP ? any one can give some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an indirect answer but you can call `phpinfo()` to display all of the `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` values. Try calling it, and searching for "X-Forwarded-For" in the web page that is displayed.

If the value is in the output, you'll easily find out where it's held. If not, then it's likely that the browser just didn't send that header.

Comment: i have checked the phpinfo,it didnt display the X-Forwarded-For server variables, how  could i enable into it.

Comment: If it wasn't shown, then the server didn't receive the header. If you're asking about this field then your application is probably behind a load balancer or proxy. Your network administrator would have to configure the load balancer to add the header to HTTP traffic.

Comment: No, if Apache receives the header then PHP will receive it.

Answer (score 1):

It will be in the `$_SERVER` superglobal

```
$_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For'];
```

Comment: it says like this Undefined index: X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this;

```
$headers = apache_request_headers(); 
$real_client_ip = $headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
```

Is that the sort of thing you need?

Comment: Is the web server running apache or nGinx?